# How do dynamic library's code know within what process it's called?

Tags: libraries, dynamic-linking

If I understood correctly, the one dylib instance is stored in one memory segment when loaded, then it becames shared **and not copied** between multiple processes virtual memories that need it. But how do it know who's calling at execution time?

E.g. I ask some library's class constructor that depends on my process name (without passing the name directly, as I can pass any really), how will it know what exactly process of multiple it's attached to did called?

(Omitting the fact that in this example meta-info is not a secret and can be retrieved with a simple system call) / The library's code even can't rely on information from every process memory it theoretically could, as the same memory-sharing scheme surely can't be applied backwards (one library <- many processes at same time) - it would be big security hole.

The situation even gets more complicated when a library need to store some process-specific info in it's class as a static property, to be shared within some particular process, and/but not every process**es** that it's attached to. I assume that, in fact, the data will be written in the process memory in a format that the class will see as it's own regular field, but again - we returned to the problem of process recognition at the level of a library's code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, pointers to the stack (where return address comes from), the heap (data storage), and some variable values or addresses are passed in CPU registers. All of these addresses are in the caller's virtual memory. The dynamic library code is running in the context of the caller, so all the syscalls behave as if the caller had done them.

I call the shared libraries with pointers to my stuff,  in my virtual space, and you call the shared libraries with pointers you your stuff,  in your virtual space.